# How can I retrieve the array elements in a different cells swift ios

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am retrieving an array elements but all the elements are being retrieved in a single cell instead of every element in every new cell. I want every element of `PDFList` array should be in every single cell.

Here is what I am getting

[image]

Here is what I done so far to get data :

```
import UIKit

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class PDFListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var PDFList = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var PDFListTable: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return PDFList.count
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = PDFListTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PDFCell") as! PDFTableViewCell
    cell.pdfLabel.text = PDFList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PDFListTable.delegate = self
    PDFListTable.dataSource = self

    PDFList = ["Form title 1, Form title 2, Form title 3,Form title 4, Form title 5, Form title 6,Form title 7, Form title 8, Form title 9,Form title 10, Form title 11, Form title 12"]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Please follow standards. Variable and function names start with lowercase letters. Class and struct names start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared single string in your PDFList.

```
PDFList = ["Form title 1", "Form title 2", "Form title 3",...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array must be like:

```
PDFList = ["Form title 1", "Form title 2", "Form title 3", "Form title 4", "Form title 5", "Form title 6", "Form title 7", "Form title 8", "Form title 9", "Form title 10", "Form title 11", "Form title 12"]
```

Inside the double quotes " " value defines the single element of array ..that's why you getting that above result.

Answer (score 0):

Your ***PDFList*** is a **String** at Index zero in **Array**. In your PDFList[IndexPath.row] will return at Index[0] where it is in first row of your table list.

Answer (score -1):

If your Array contains single string then you can access different element for different cell.

For e.g:- cell.label.text = arrlist[indexPath.row]

But if your array contains the key value data then you can access the data in the following form:-

"arrData": [
    {
      "latitude": "46.1817",
      "longitude": "150.7960",
    },
    {
      "latitude": "28.1069",
      "longitude": "62.0532",
    }
  ]

For e.g:- cell.label.text = arrData["latitude"][row]